# Format console output in Python to have fixed width

Tags: python-3.x, output, command-line-interface, string-formatting

I'm building a CLI and want to format my output to be max 60 characters wide. I don't want to hyphenate, but move the word to the next line if it is too long and don't want to manually insert `\n` characters in my text to achieve this goal. I have been playing around with Pthons `.format()` function, but to no avail.

Example: Line in output should end after **'blurry'**:

```sh
===================== IMAGE-DELETE CLI =====================


Welcome to the IMAGE-DELETE CLI. Based on your input blurry and under / overexposed images will be deleted and to free up some disk space.


Lets get started...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `textwrap` module.

```
import textwrap

lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=60) # text is the variable contains what you want to print out

# then print it out
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Hope this helps.  See more info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html